# Which image to use to deploy a Seaside 3.0 application with Pharo 1.4?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I have developed a Seaside 3.0 application in Pharo 1.4 and want do deploy it on Linode.

What (small) image do i load my application into for that purpose? And how?

I found [Project Pharo Kernel 1.4 Seaside](https://ci.lille.inria.fr/pharo/view/Pharo-Kernel%201.4/job/Pharo%20Kernel%201.4%20Seaside/) on the Pharo Jenkins Server, but as it seems to be without graphical user interface i do not know how to load my application into it and how to configure Seaside. Is it a good idea to use this image? How would i configure it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best thing yo can do is to take a regular "1.4 summer" image and execute.

```
ScriptLoader new cleanUpForProduction.
```

That will give you a perfectly operating 9m-sized image.

Comment: OK, thank you. It works very well. My Seaside image goes from 27mb to 14mb. I guess i can unload further unneeded packages as it's done in ScriptLoader..